# Создание нового узла в Firebase Realtime

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

У меня есть база данных, в которой уже есть два дочерних узла, которые уже заполнены данными. Мое приложение основано на рецептах. Я хочу , чтобы рецепты, которые добавляет пользователь себе в "Избранные", сохранялись в базу данных. Для этого я хочу создать новый дочерний узел Users, в который хочу записывать id пользователя, когда он зарегистрировался. Затем по этому id будет добавляться название рецептов, и когда пользователь будет авторизовываться, я буду получать id текущего пользователя и отображать название рецептов. Проблема заключается в следующем: Я хочу создать новый дочерний узел Users, в который будут записываться id пользователей. Но пустой дочерний узел я создать не могу. Как я могу реализовать это ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вас верно понял? Создаем группу с именем Users `val myRef = database.getReference("Users").child("idUsers")`и создаем новую подкатегорию с именем idUsers и сохраняем необходимую информацию `myRef.setValue("Рецепт Америка")`

Вы получите следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня есть родительский узел myRef, затем я хочу добавить в него дочерний узел Users, чтобы в него записывать id пользователей. Но т.к. у меня нет значения для ключа (Users) , при нажатии Добавить, он автоматом удаляется.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, ваше решение возможно и правильное, но вопрос теперь другой -  можно ли не создавать под категорию  , а сразу записывать id в группу Users ?

Comment: Т.е. если узел не существует, то Firebase автоматически создаст новый дочерний узел ?

Comment: Да, мой вариант и будет это делать, если не передать .child("idUsers"), то группа Users будет всегда перезаписываться

Comment: Да, она сама создаст Users и в ней поле id пользователя и информацию. Сейчас покажу.

Comment: Users запишется как дочерний узел , верно же ? Он не запишется как родительский, что в итоге очистит существующую информацию в бд ?

Comment: Нет, он не очистить, а создаст еще одно дерево информации, в текущей базе данных.

Comment: "19322", "27100" -  это вы дали название ? Id это же то,что выше Users

Comment: Да, это я, через код. Вам дерево информации нужно или такой вид Users1 - рецепт ***,  Users2- рецепт, ** * итд?

Comment: IdUsers1 - названия рецептов, IdUsers2 - названия рецептов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92915/discussion-between-famous-and-segrei-ulanov).